# Python For loop stuck and not iterating

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

The following is my code for KNN Classifier iterations for the value of K.
When I'm running this code, the loop is getting stuck on run.
I had to kill the program several times and re run it.
Still no luck!

```
CrossValAccuracy=[]
F1=[]
for i in range(50):

    KNNModel= KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i+1)
    KNNModel.fit(train_data_x,train_data_y)
    CrossValAccuracy.append(np.mean(cross_val_score(KNNModel, train_data_x, train_data_y, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')))
    F1.append(np.mean(cross_val_score(KNNModel,train_data_x,train_data_y,cv=10,scoring='f1_micro')))

best_k= np.argmax(F1)+1

print ("Best value of K based on model F1-score is:",best_k)
```

Comment: How can you tell it's stuck and not just busy computing?

Comment: You're running 50 iterations of classifier training, PLUS 100 iterations of `cross_val_score(KNNModel...` . That's a lot of compute time. Have you tried the built-in GridSearchCV instead?

Comment: @AndrasDeak, its been more than half an hour since it's been running

Comment: @G.Anderson, its just 10 iterations of cross fold validation.

Comment: `for i in range(50)` means do everything in this indented block 50 times. Inside the code block, you are running `cross_val_score` twice, with different targets. That means 50 model fits, and 50+50 x 10-fold cv scoring

Comment: Since `for i in range(50)` is guaranteed not to be an infinite loop, my best guess would still be that it's running, albeit slow (perhaps you're running out of memory, [slowing down your system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science))). Try adding some prints or just wrapping your `range(50)` with `tqdm.tqdm` in the loop to get a progress bar. Something that tells you that the loop is progressing.